# Trac login form

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, trac

I am having trouble getting the html login form to work instead of the default pop up authentication login form. This is what I have in my trac.ini for the account-manager and components sections:

```
[account-manager]
generated_password_length = 8
hash_method = HtDigestHashMethod
password_file = /trac/.htpasswds/passwd
password_format = htpasswd
password_store = HtPasswdStore

[components]
acct_mgr.admin.accountmanageradminpage = enabled
acct_mgr.db.sessionstore - disabled
acct_mgr.pwhash.htdigesthashmethod =disabled
acct_mgr.web_ui.accountmodule = enabled
acct_mgr.web_ui.loginmodule = enabled
acct_mgr.web_ui.registrationmodule = enabled
trac.web.auth.loginmodule = disabled
webadmin.* enabled
```

Do these settings look correct?

Comment: Has anybody encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of typos in your `[components]` section; in particular, you have a `-` instead of an `=` on the `acct_mgr.db.sessionstore` line, and you are missing an equal sign on the `webadmin` line.  Assuming you are using Trac 0.11, webadmin is now part of core, so you shouldn't have to explicitly enable it anyway.

If fixing those things does not solve the problem, be sure to enable logging, restart your webserver, try again, and check the `trac.log` file for clues.

During US business hours, there's usually someone hanging around `#trac` on freenode.